# RewriteRule not working in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written a rewrite rule so my website does not require URL to have .php in which looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

But when I created a mobile version of the site and put files in a subfolder called "m" the rewriteRule doesn't work for the subfolder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have rewrite rules in an htaccess file in your `/m/` folder?

Comment: Is your mobile site it's own `VirtualHost` or just a subfolder you access with `www.domain.tld/m/`? I think it's your `[^/]` that make it fail though.

Comment: @JonLin the htaccess is in the root directory

Comment: @Qben It is my own VirtualHost

Comment: @braza Than I assume your `.htaccess` file was never copied to the mobile site `DocumentRoot`, meaning `<path>/m/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of those rules and place them in an htaccess file in the `/m/` folder.

You *may* need to include a base, and don't forget to turn on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On

# may not need this
#RewriteBase /m/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I just worked it out after your comment! It does need the RewriteBase /m/ to work.